# Deployed package is missing config and certs. Activation is running into Error - FABRIC_E_CERTIFICATE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I'm facing issues when I deploy my service fabric app to cluster. Deployment completed with below error.

> Error event: SourceId='System.Hosting', Property='Activation:1.0'.
>   There was an error during activation.Failed to configure certificate
>   permissions. Error FABRIC_E_CERTIFICATE_NOT_FOUND.

This certificate is part of config package. However when I login to VM, I don't see the package deployed with config folder. I checked that package which is built locally, it looks correct with Config folder and certificate. But when this  package is deployed to cluster then Config pkg is missing on VM and hence service activation fails with Certificate not found error.

All the details can be found in the issue I have logged on [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/1354).

Snippet from ApplicationManifest which refers to certificate:

```
  <ContainerHostPolicies CodePackageRef="Code">
    <CertificateRef Name="SecretsCert" DataPackageRef="Config" DataPackageVersion="Version" RelativePath="PFX PATH INSIDE CONFIG" IsPasswordEncrypted="true" Password="NOTMYPASSWORD"/>       
    <RepositoryCredentials AccountName="Container Registry Name" Password="[Registry Key]" PasswordEncrypted="true" />        
  </ContainerHostPolicies>
```